# Way of seeing what queries were run when?

Tags: mysql, sql, logging, centos

My mysql server seems to be getting spikes in memory usage throughout the week. I'm thinking this is because of some long/complex queries that are being run. Is there a way to see some kind of db logs that show what query was run at what time (maybe even how long it took to execute?) Is there a way to see this in the db itself or on the machine? (it's running on CentOS 6.3? If not, is there a tool or app that can do this?

Thanks very much,

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heared about TODO application. This is very useful application where you have inbuilt functions() to run your queries and lots of things in order to reduce complexity of queries. May be this application help you here.

Comment: Plus 1 because @ajay does not have sufficient reputation to post comments.